# How do I download Visual Studio in a drive other than C?

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

So basically I wanna Install Visual Studio in the E drive of my computer because it has way more space available than my C drive. I tried changing the path to a folder that I created in the E drive but it just threw a error and said that it isn't possible to do that. So what am I supposed to do to install VS in my E drive?

The attached image shows the default paths that I am just not able to change.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio can be installed on any drive, once installed you should go under tools, options and check environment paths as default paths for projects is under C:\Users...

Comment: wait I don't get it. I can't find any thing labeled as "tools" in Visual Studio installer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).